# download a file from rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, download

I think i have got a very special question: "How can I Download a file from an rails app...?" This question is asked a few times but every solution does not work for my problem. So i need a good railer for that ;-) or 2 more eyes...

In my controller i got a helper method:

```
def download_file
    send_data "#{Rails.root}/public/files/sample.txt"
end

helper_method :download_file
```

In my view i called this method:

```
<%= link_to 'Download File',  :action => :download_files %>
```

But i got an

`No route matches {:action=>"download_files", ...}` error

I tried to link it directly to my public folder file but it doesnt work

Can you may help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because no route matches action download_files, I hope that clears it ! Add route

```
get "download_files", :to => "controller#action"
```

or if your controller is named `foo`.

```
resources :foo do 
   get 'download_files' , :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: I chose 2nd way to create this download-link but now i get an error: "Unknown action
The action 'download_files' could not be found for CustomersController" but in my customer controller theres a method called "download_files" why doesnt it work?

Comment: buddy, when it says action, it means its searching for a file named download_files inside app/views/customers folder

Comment: @GeorgeKrause no problem friend, every one starts from scratch.